# Alamofire - Bad request

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire, postman, objectmapper

I am afraid I cannot share the API url. But I have checked on **Postman**, it works. It is a **POST** request and following is the response :

```
{
    "user_key": "b0aebdedb15e2beaaf479ca3c4f8227e8e970681"
}
```

Postman screenshot :

[image]

In code, this is the request I am making using Alamofire :

```
Alamofire.request("some url", method: .post, parameters: params, encoding: URLEncoding.httpBody, headers: ["Content-Type":"application/json"])
            .responseObject { (response: DataResponse<User>) in

                let userResponse = response.result.value
                print("")
    }
```

But userResponse comes to be nil. This is the **User** object :

```
import ObjectMapper

class User: Mappable {

    var authToken: String?

     required init?(map: Map) {

    }

    func mapping(map: Map) {
        self.authToken <- map["user_key"]
    }


}
```

I am using [**ObjectMapper**](https://github.com/tristanhimmelman/AlamofireObjectMapper) here.

Assuming the it is not a `JSON` object, I tried to handle it as a `String` :

```
 Alamofire.request("some url", method: .post, parameters: params, encoding: URLEncoding.httpBody, headers: ["Content-Type":"application/json"])
            .responseString { (response: DataResponse<String>) in
                let dataUser = response.data as! Any
                let dataUser1 = response.data as! AnyObject
                let error = response.error
                let code = response.response?.statusCode
                print(response.value)
                print(response.result.value)
        }
```

Still, nothing. I am not able to retrieve the value. The status code however comes out to be 400 (bad request).
What exactly is it ? `JSON` object or `String` ? How do I fix this ?

Comment: Double check request `method`, `encoding`, `endPoint` and `headers` sent with `Alamofire` request and in `Postman`. If backend guy is in reach, its a good idea to annoy him a little bit :)

Comment: Error 400 generally means that the server rejects does not accept your request so there's no user data returned, that is why the userResponse is nil.

Comment: @Kamran : How to check encoding on Postman ?

Comment: @IgorN : Yes. I already mentioned that.

Comment: Under Body, there is a dropdown on right of body options.

Comment: @Kamran : But that is for content-type, not encoding.

Comment: check you'r parameters and try to replace this `URLEncoding.httpBody` to `JSONEncoding.default`

Comment: @a.masri : That was it. Thanks. You may answer the question for reference.

Comment: @Nitish add my answer , good luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try to replace

this `URLEncoding.httpBody` to `JSONEncoding.default`

**JSONEncoding.default**

Uses `JSONSerialization` to create a JSON representation of the parameters object, which is set as the body of the request. The `Content-Type` HTTP header field of an encoded request is set to `application/json`.

[Alamofire reference](http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/Alamofire/4.0.1/Structs/JSONEncoding.html)